# Proving properties of linear maps on one-dimensional vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

An exercise from the book "Linear Algebra Done Right" asks to prove the following:

'Show that every linear map from a one-dimensional vector space to itself is multiplication by some scalar. More precisely, prove that if $\textrm{dim}\ V = 1$ and $T \in L(V, V)$ then there exists $a \in F$ such that $Tv = av$ for all $v \in V$.'

I'm a bit stuck here. My thought is: surely $V$ contains within it a basis for $V$, meaning there's a linear combination of vectors in $V$ that can express each element of the vector space, i.e. $a_1v_1,...,a_nv_n = v$ where $v_1,...,v_n \in V$ and $v \in V$. Now it seems that the key thing is to show that this linear combination only involves one element, i.e. is of form $a_kv_k$ and this must somehow fall out from the constraint that $V$ is one dimensional, but I don't really see it?

The dimension of $V$, $\textrm{dim} V$ is defined as $n$ if the vector space is $R^{n}$ or $F^{n}$ basically.

Comment: How do you define dimension of a vector space?

Comment: @GitGud: updated my question to answer this

Comment: OK, I'm guessing your definition says that $\dim (V)=n$ if, and only if, there is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb R^n$. You have $n=1$, so $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. What is a basis of $\mathbb R$? How many elements are in it?

Comment: @GitGud: an obvious basis for $R^{n}$ is $((1,0,0,...,0),(0,1,0,...,0), ...)$ for $n$ lists (i.e. 0 in all places except the $n$th). You can assume any basis for $R^{n}$ that you'd like though; not sure how this affects the question?

Comment: So a basis for $\mathbb R$ is $\{1\}$, just one element as you wished.

Comment: @GitGud: still don't follow how you get $Tv = av$? Is there a constructive way to derive that $a$ based on $T$ and the fact that the basis is one-dimensional?

Comment: There's some miscommunication here. I thought you were asking how you could ensure that any linear combination 'only involves one element'. Is this not the question?

Comment: @GitGud: Ah, I get it

Comment: I got the text you're following, the definition you posted of dimension isn't the one in use. Do you still require help to prove the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without words (almost):

$$\dim_{\Bbb F}V=1\iff V=\text{Span}_{\Bbb F}\{v\}\;,\;\;v\neq 0\iff \forall\,x\in V\;\exists\,\alpha\in\Bbb F\;\;s.t.\;\;x=\alpha v\implies$$

$$Tx=T(\alpha v)=\alpha Tv$$

Now, since $\;Tv=\beta v\;,\;\;\beta\in\Bbb F\;$, substitute above and we're done....

Comment: Why do you need the Span condition at all? I also don't understand the second $\iff$

Comment: The span is there (1) first, because it is true, and (2) second, because it makes thing easier to understand, imo. The second $\;\iff\;$ is just the definition of "vector belonging to the span of a set of vectors".